# How To Iterate Over JSON Object?

Tags: android, json, loops

**MY JSON RESPONSE**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": "1",
      "phone_number": "data",
      "name": "data",
      "number": "",
      "token": "data",
      "email": "data",
      "website": "data",
      "profile_picture": "data"
    },
    {
      "uid": "2",
      "phone_number": "data",
      "name": "data",
      "number": "data",
      "token": "data",
      "email": "data",
      "website": "data",
      "profile_picture": "data"
    }
  ]
}
```

And in Android, I have a object for this `Friend.java`

```
 jObject = new JSONObject(Response);
 if(!error){
          Toast.makeText(PasswordActivity.this, "Data Got Perfectly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
/*This Is Where Will Loop May Start*/
//loop{

          JSONObject object = jObject.getJSONObject("data");
          Friend friend = new   Friend(object.getString("name"),
                                       object.getString("number"),
                                       object.getString("token"),
                                       object.getString("email"),
                                       object.getString("website"); 
                                       object.getString("profile_picture"));
dbHelper.addFriend(friend);
//}
/*This Is Where Will Loop May End*/
}
```

How can I iterate the data on Android to save data on SQLite;

Comment: Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) OR See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: You're going to have trouble iterating it, since it isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Should I Follow Your Name Or Not? Jokes Apart, Can You Tell Me Why It's Not A Valid JSON?

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/ See what results you get there.

Comment: @jdv Ok let me try

Comment: @jdv  It  Says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 137"

Comment: Someone edited your JSON strings and fixed them. Now you are seeing how you can't parse two separate JSON strings. This is where you need to do some research. The Linked article tells you everything you need to get started.

Comment: Even after fixing those broken keys, it's still not valid. Two valid JSON objects back to back isn't valid JSON. They need to be in an array (`[]`) separated by a comma.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes You Are Right, Let Me Edit My Response And Make It Proper JSON And I Will Do Research Then.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I Have Edited My JSON please take a look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way `data` is an Array

```
JSONArray jsonarray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
String number = jsonobject.getString("number");
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Your Answer Worked For Me.